# Separable ODE and assumptions on the solution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Suppose I have an ODE-problem of the form:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x'(t)= g(t) h(x(t))\\
x(t_{0})=x_{0},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where both functions $g$ and $h$ are smooth. Suppose further that $h(t)=0$ if and only if $t=0$.

Now, if $x_{0} =0$, then clearly the solution of the problem is the constant function $x=0$. Else, if $x_{0} \neq 0$, then there exists an open interval containing $x_{0}$ where $h$ is non-zero. Thus, dividing by $h(x(t))$, we can solve the separable ODE using the standard method.

Suppose that, when $x_{0} \neq 0$, the solution of
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x'(t)/h(x(t))= g(t) \\
x(t_{0})=x_{0},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
is well-defined and non-zero for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Since this solution also solves the first system, by uniqueness, it must be *the* solution of the first system.

My question is: Is this reasoning correct? I am a bit confused because it seems to me like we are finding the solution under the assumption that it is non-zero. What is the best way of handling this problem?

Comment: Related question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1238669/242708

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is wrong. Consider the following IVP:
$$ x'=x-1,x(0)=0. $$
Clearly it has the solution
$$ x=1-e^t $$
which is not a zero solution.

Comment: I have not claimed the statement that you report. I assumed that $h(t)=0$ if and only if $t=0$, which your function $h$ surely does not meet. However, this was not the point of my question.